# Sending data through UDP sockets

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, udp

I'm able to setup a TCP connection between a client and a server, but just have a question about the setup for a UDP connection.

For TCP I used the following format

```
CLIENT                   SERVER
------                   ------
WSAStartup()             WSAStartup()
s=socket(x, y, z)        s=socket(x, y, z)
 -                       bind()
 -                       listen()
connect()                accept()
send()                    -
 -                       recv()
closesocket(s)           closesocket(s)
WSAcleanup()             WSACleanup()
```

Now my question is for the UDP setup. Since it is connectionless, would this be the right setup?

```
CLIENT                   SERVER
------                   ------
WSAStartup()             WSAStartup()
s=socket(x, y, z)        s=socket(x, y, z)
bind()                   bind()
sendto()                  -
 -                       recvfrom()
closesocket(s)           closesocket(s)
WSAcleanup()             WSACleanup()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you show is the correct setup for UDP.

Comment: Do I need to call bind() if i'm not using listen()?

Comment: Yes, since it establishes the port that recvfrom() will read on, just like it establishes the port that listen() accepts clients on.